# Why are types of a named function different from an anonymous one in scala

Tags: function, scala, anonymous

In scala, a named function is defined as:

```
scala> def addOne(x: Int): Int = x+1
addOne: (x: Int)Int

scala> :type addOne
(x: Int)Int
```

And an anonymous one as:

```
scala> val addOne = (x:Int) => x+1
addOne: Int => Int = <function1>

scala> :type addOne
Int => Int
```

Why do their types look different?

Why can't a named function be passed as an argument to another function?

Shouldn't both be treated uniformly from type and first-order behavior point of views?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`def addOne(x: Int): Int` is not a function in scala. It's a method of some object.

Functions like `val addOne = (x:Int) => x+1` are objects of type `FunctionN` (in this case `Function1`) with method `apply`.

One can use method as function in scala - compiler can create a function from method, for instance:

```
scala> List(1, 2, 3).map((1).+) // or just `1+`
res0: List[Int] = List(2, 3, 4)
```

In this case method `+` of object `1` is used as function `x => (1).+(x)`.

```
scala> List(1, 2, 3).foreach(println)
1
2
3
```

Method `println` of object `Predef` is used as function `s => Predef.println(s)`.

Since version `2.10` you can't use `:type` on methods:

```
scala> def addOne(x: Int): Int = x+1
addOne: (x: Int)Int

scala> :type addOne
<console>:9: error: missing arguments for method addOne;
follow this method with `_' if you want to treat it as a partially applied function
       addOne
       ^
```